# "Ground" to "ground" testing 120V, plus circuit measuring 30V?

Tags: electrical

I was replacing a duplex outlet in my basement and discovered 1) a circuit carrying 30V and 2) testing 120V between two bare "ground" wires from separate circuits.

Two pairs of black/white/bare wire enter an outlet box and are pigtailed to an outlet. I traced it using a Breaker Finder to Circuit 4 (15A), which I turned off at the breaker. I tested with a non-contact tester and found voltage. I shut off power at the main, disconnected the pigtailed wires, then turned it back on at the main (with power from Circuit 4 still off) so I could find out why there was voltage.

I discovered that Pair B from the bottom of the outlet box is Circuit 9 (15A), and it carries 30V of electricity. Pair A comes from a ceiling light in my laundry. Pair B comes from outside where it is attached to a GFCI with three pairs of Romex entering the box.

Here is a table showing voltages when measured from each wire to each other wire, testing both common and red (?) when using a multimeter.

[image: Table of Voltages]

Outlets nearby are correctly wired with a socket tester. Home built in the mid 80's.

My questions are, "Why does the circuit measure 30V?", "Why would bare wire to bare wire from two separate circuits measure 120V?", and finally "Is this safe?"

Comment: Can we have a photo of the inside of the GFCI box?

Comment: You're seeing phantom voltage from capacitive coupling.   Do the tests again with an incandescent night-light also plugged in and turned on.

Comment: Are you sure that chart is correct?  One measurement says Black-A to Black-B is 0V, the other says Black-B to Black-A is 30V.  White-A to Black-B is 1.5V, and Black-B to White-A is 118.7V.

Comment: @Harper How can I test with the wires separated and an incandescent plugged in and turned on? When the outlet is assembled, it tests 120V, not 150V.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can't get a photo of the GFCI right now, what are you wanting to see? Come to think of it, if three pairs come in and are pigtailed together, and all are attached to the line screws, I imagine it won't work correctly since anything operating as load should come off of load. Perhaps I should replace it with a new GFCI, put line onto line alone, and pigtail jumpers with the neutrals and hots to attach to the load screws.

Comment: @Tester101 Correct, when the black lead is on Black A and the red lead is on Black B, the voltage is 0V. When the black lead is on Black B and the red lead is on Black A, the voltage is 30V. Likewise White-A/Black-B measurement is also correct.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. I re-wired the GFCI. Made things worse. I separated all three pairs of wires, turned on the circuits, and tested that the middle pair was hot (120V hot to neutral) and the side pairs were not. I turned off the circuits and put the middle (hot) pair on line, and pigtailed the two remaining pairs onto load. When I turned on the circuit, I found the GFCI had tripped. I reset it with a wooden dowel and it shorted out (metal box -- maybe I should replace with plastic), and tripped the circuit breaker (not the GFCI).

Comment: @MinnesotaDIY -- try just nutting off the load wires and seeing if the GFCI works on its own

Comment: @MinnesotaDIY Actually, you can plug the night-light into any "upstream" receptacle (that you know definitely is in the same circuit between the test-point and the breaker.)  Or you can hook the wires to 2 receptacles. Or use a low-impedance meter such as the old style analog-meter types.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. With the load wires nutted and not connected to the GFCI, works fine. Crowded box, so I will try reconnecting them to the Load and wrapping the GFCI with a loop of electrical tape. Perhaps accidental contact between screws and box/grounds?

Comment: @MinnesotaDIY yeah, that could very well have done it for the breaker trip

Comment: What type of meter is it?  You have it set for measuring AC volts, right?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OK, well, the replaced GFCI works when it's not smashing into the metal box. I'll get it back into the box, but I imagine the mystery will continue indoors, as the wiring should still be the same indoors in terms of 30V and 120V heading into the same outlet.

Comment: @Tester101 It looks like [this Gardner Bender](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Gardner-Bender-GDT-311-Gardner-Bender-GDT-311-3-Function-Digital-Multimeter/21192913) multimeter. It's set for 200 at the top in black. I believe that's 200 volts AC, symbol is a V with a ~ over it.

Comment: @MinnesotaDIY how old is the battery in it?  When you measure voltage, you're measuring the potential difference between two points.  Since it's alternating current, there's no positive and negative. Swapping the leads shouldn't make a difference, since the electrical potential between the two points should be the same. I think your meter might be busted.

Comment: @Tester101 Pretty odd that it consistently does this, that is, I can reproduce that table every time. I'll give the batteries a swap.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Nevermind on the GFCI, its faulting out again. I'm about to throw in the towel on this one and call in an electrician.

Comment: @Tester101 Replaced batteries and also nutted off load lines at GFCI and 30V has disappeared. Updated table, still confused on ground-to-ground testing 120V:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXwlI.png

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel External load lines nutted off and GFCI is not tripping, measures 120V. Updated table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXwlI.png

Comment: What does "*nutted off load lines*" mean?  You're troubleshooting, but you're making too many changes at once.  If the meter was crap at the start, you need to go back to the start once the meter is fixed.  Put everything back the way you found it, and start again with a good meter.

Comment: If the grounds are 120 volts apart, one or both are floating (not grounded), and one or both are energized.  Test each ground back to a known good ground, and make sure they're both properly grounded. Once they are, the breaker should trip if either is energized.  During your testing of the grounds, make sure the breakers are off.

Comment: It might also help if you sketch a diagram of the circuits, so you can visualize how everything is interconnected.